# Handling Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click: With Capybara, ruby, Webdriver

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a UI test that goes to a list of articles and selects the load_more button until this is no longer available (because all articles have loaded). The problem is the button has been hidden at this point rather than removed and is returning this error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Element <div 
class="">...</div> is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element 
would receive the click: <div class="" id="" data-module-name="">... 
</div>

(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540469 
ruby-2.5.1/gems/selenium-webdriver 
3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok'
```

I have tried a few loop types but for this, if we assume I'm using

```
while world.page.has_load_more?
  world.page.load_more.click
break if world.page.has_load_more? == false
end
```

The question is how do I tell Selenium this is ok and not to error, so I can continue with the next step in my test case(cucumber). I realise that the choice of loop type may also be incorrect, so feel free to suggest changes there as well.

Comment: No, your assumptions are wrong, this error wouldn't happen when button is hidden instead it would happen when button is overlayed by some other element.

Comment: Thanks - Should have been clearer. I meant hidden as in hidden/ invisible to the eye

Comment: Your invisibility is not invisible to selenium, If element appears in the down of the page, it's invisible to you but it's not invisible to selenium, selenium consider something invisible when element exist but still it's hidden but anyhow your errors that it's not invisible! If it's invisible, then it would have thrown the error `element is invisible`

Comment: thanks for the details

Comment: If you still want to click, you can inject JavaScript in your selenium code which doesn't do any checking but you would be fall out control of your implicit wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as Rajagopalan has pointed out, the error that you're getting is not that your element is not visible (as in hidden by CSS) but that it is overlapped by another element. You can call `save_and_open_screenshot` to see what element is overlapping the button (possibly a fixed footer, etc?). Make sure you've set the window size large enough so you don't have elements unintentionally overlapping and make sure you're running the latest version of Capybara since it attempts to deal with overlapped elements in selenium by scrolling them into view if possible.

Secondly, the loop in your question doesn't make a lot of sense having both the `while` and `break` since they check the same thing.  Also, assuming the "load more" button is loading and appending to the page via AJAX, you probably need to wait for the new elements to load before checking if the button exists (`click` does not wait for actions to complete since it has no idea what actions could/would be triggered).  That would then become a structure something like

```
 while page.has_button?('Load More')
   # Get the current number of visible articles
   article_count = page.all('div.article').count # Use whatever selector would match an article in the list
   # click the button
   page.click_button('Load More')
   # ensure more articles have loaded
   expect(page).to have_css('div.article', minimum: article_count + 1)
end
```

Note: You'll probably want to change that to use whatever page object methods you are using (`has_load_more?`, etc) but the general logic should be correct

Comment: Thanks for this - The loop makes perfect sense. Regarding the first part looking into it more, it looks like the dev team are using some bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) for a responsive design. They "hide" the element by adding .d-none

Comment: when the article list is exhausted. Not sure if this changes the first part of your answer but I thought it was worth mentioning, even just for clarity.

Comment: @SuleyMahmoud Assuming the bootstrap CSS is properly loaded `.d-none` assigns `display:none` to the element, but if that was your issue you should be getting an `unable to find element` (or equivalent) error, not `other element would receive the click`.  This all assumes whatever your `has_load_more?` method does, it ignores hidden elements and the `click` method is the standard Capybara `click`.  Basically, you have an element overlapping the "button" (I assume it's actually a div from the error) and you need to work out why (look at screenshot)